# Is it possible to edit source files while push is in progress?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

Is it possible to edit source files while push is in progress? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. Push pushes commits, trees and blobs from the object database, not files.

Pull, on the other hand, not only fetches objects into object database but also updates files. So avoid editing while pulling.

Comment: OTOH, if you use `fetch` (which is often a good idea since it has less "auto-magical" behavior) then this, like push, only cares about the database

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `git push`, it is the contents of the stage which is getting pushed.  But that contents has already been committed, so really the commit is what is getting pushed.  Therefore, editing source files might make your working directory dirty, but it would not affect the stage, certainly would not affect any commits, and therefore could not affect the push.

Comment: Actually it is contents of the database, not the stage, that get pushed.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Conceptually it is the stage which gets pushed.  If it were not possible to modify the stage then the underlying database also could not be modified.

Comment: No, it isn't. Conceptually it is the stage that gets *committed* during `git commit`, but the stage has nothing to do with a push.  If this weren't so, it would only be possible to push what's checked out